# Deleted rows but database size is still large

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express which has maximum database size limit of 10 GB. Every month I hit the limit and the application can't store more data.

To overcome this problem we run a job every month which takes backup of the database for last 30 days and deletes the data for those 30 days from the respective tables. After delete also the size remains high.

Shrinking the database, truncating the tables, table clean up, Shrink the database and rebuild the index, delete the tables and recreate them. Every time shrinking the database is not good so kept as a last option.

Apart from this is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: You should consider purchasing an edition without these limitations. If the budget does not allow that, perhaps switching to a less expensive product may be an option, too?

Answer (score 6):

Do *all* tables have clustered indexes? Without this, rebuilding indexes won't help you.

If you haven't and don't want to add them, your only option is to use [DBCC SHRINKFILE with NOTRUNCATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) to force the data pages to compact